# JSON file is valid but I can't parse it

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, handlebars.js

The valid JSON file below:

```
{
"response": {
    "player_count": 6453,
    "result": 1
}
}
```

When I use the console.log(req.responseText) command I get:

```
{
"response": {
    "player_count": 6453,
    "result": 1
}
}
```

When using the following from my Node server (by sending the JSON file to it) All I get is [object Object] when using the code below: This is where the problem lies I think.

```
app.post('/steam-output', function(req,res){
var params = [];
for (var p in req.body){
params.push({'name':p,'value':req.body[p]})
}
console.log(params);
console.log(req.body);
var context = {};
context.dataList = params;
res.render('steam-output', context);
// steam-output is a handlebars file which is what my Node.js server is running
});

//here is the steam-output.handlebars file
<h1></h1>
<ul>
{{#each dataList}}
   <li>{{this.name}}: {{this.value}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

And it also just comes up with [object Object].
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated (please no links to other sites unless they have thorough examples of fixing this).

This problem doesn't happen if it is just this JSON file:

```
 {
    "player_count": 6453,
    "result": 1
 }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't parse" mean?  What does JSON.parse give you?  If I pass that string to JSON.parse I get the expected object in memory (where `foo.response == { player_count: 6041, result :1 }`)

Comment: I mean it just becomes [object Object], basically something went wrong...

Comment: JSON.parse returns an object.  In the Firefox console, when I do `a = JSON.parse(your json)` it tells me that's an Object { response: Object } and I can look at `a.response` etc.  Does your parsed object have any attributes? Parsing invalid JSON should return an error, not an Object.

Comment: Oh.  Then I guess the real problem is in the handlebars code and code on the Node server...

Comment: @Rex: That seems to be the correct result. Try `console.log`ging the result instead of `alert`ing it (or using anything else that casts it to a string)

Comment: @Bergi I have been using console.log, the problem isn't in the parsing, it is in the Javascript code that I am using via Node (detailed above)

Comment: @Rex: I don't get how the JSON you posted is related to that node.js code. Is `req.body` the JSON string? And where exactly are you getting `[object Object]`, as a `this.value`?

Comment: @Bergi I am getting it when loading the steam-output.handlebars file.  I am sending the JSON file to the Node server which then posts each of the elements of the JSON file (name, then value).  But it doesn't seem to work when there are multiple levels (see the difference between the one that works vs the one that doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just iterating the wrong part of the JSON. What happens if you change your `for in` loop to this?

```
for (var p in req.body.response){
    params.push({'name':p,'value':req.body.response[p]})
}
```

Comment: No problem! I almost didn't spot that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var esr = { 
   "response":{  
      "player_count":6453,
      "result":1
   }
}

var responseText = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(esr)));
alert(responseText.response.player_count); //out put 6453
```

Comment: That seems to work, however do you know if there is any way I could modify my code above to automatically do that for each element, as I guess that is my real problem now? (Because most times I need to have it be automatic as I won't know how many elements there are or the names of each of them).